# Diretiva para criar div, label e input

Tags: angularjs-directives

Bom dia, criei uma diretiva para criar uma div, um label e um input, porém o atributo ng-model não está funcionando.

No exemplo, o criado dinamicamente não funciona que é o primeiro, e o criado manualmente que é o segundo funciona.

https://plnkr.co/edit/1mWr6a6rLpvMiqAJe4jy?p=preview

Já fiz várias tentativas e nada.

Desde já obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

O que esta faltando no seu código é compilar o html com um escopo para ele saber em quem fazer o bind dos models.

De uma olhada no fork que fiz do seu [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/S34hZZDKIvz2X2fOWk8u?p=preview).

Mas para deixar mais claro, de uma olhada aqui:

Injete o `$compile` na sua diretiva pois ele será o responsável por compilar o html que você escreveu dinamicamente na sua diretiva.

```
app.directive('divCadastro', ['$compile', function($compile) {...
```

E na hora de fazer o `element.append()` compile seu html passando o escopo da sua controller:

```
element.append($compile(input)(scope.$parent));
```

De uma olhada na documentação do [$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) quando puder, mas ja adiantando.

```
$compile({html a ser compilado})({escopo para fazer bind})
```

Estou chamando o escopo assim `scope.$parent` pois você quer fazer o bind com o escopo da controller pai da diretiva. Se você passar apenas `scope` o angular vai tentar fazer o bind com a sua própria diretiva.

---

### UPDATE

Vi sua dúvida sobre os dados dinâmicos não atualizarem o `$scope`.
Simplesmente inicialize a variável na controller:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.propriedade = {};
  $scope.manipulaPropriedade = function(propriedade) {
    console.log(propriedade)         ;
  }
});
```

Não é uma boa prática criar variáveis dinâmicas no `$scope`. Imagine alguém que vá dar manutenção tentando adivinhar de onde vem essa variável chamada mais tarde dentro de algum método.

Comment: Eu já tinha feito altumas tentativas nesse sentido, mas sem sucess.

Valeu Mesmo, muito obrigado

Comment: Ficou muito bom, funcionando filé, só tem um pequeno detalhe, ele não está sendo validado no form, nesse caso eu tenho que compilá-lo no form, ao invés de:
element.append($compile(input)(scope.$parent));

Teria que ser algo do tipo:
element.append($compile(input)(formulario));
Mas não estou conseguindo chegar até ele, teria tipo um $parents('iddoform')?

Comment: Você pode atualizar seu plnkr com o formulário pra eu testar?

Comment: Olha ai, o formulário só leva em consideração o segundo campo, que foi criado manualmente, o primeiro, que foi criado pela diretiva ele ignora.

https://plnkr.co/edit/PIZUtNE5XEnJAMW7GU8r?p=preview

Comment: Tentei aqui algumas coisas mas não consegui colocar ele pra ser validado. Em outro momento eu tento estudar isso. Tente pesquisar sobre como validar form com campos dinâmicos com angular.

Comment: Show, valeu, muito obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: A solução era primeiro incluir depois compilar, troquei a linha selecionada pelas duas de baixo.

//element.append($compile(input)(scope.$parent));
var result = element.append(input);
$compile(result)(scope.$parent);

Comment: Testei no seu plnkr, funcionou legal, boa!

Comment: Campeão, boa tarde, cara eu estou incrementando aquela rotina, agora ela está criando os campos buscando os dados de um arquivo com uma variável JSON, está tudo funcionando, porém há um detalhe que é o seguinte: Quando crio os elementos do formulário, e digito em algum desses elemento, eles não atualizam o $scope, mas se eu colocar um elemento criado na mão junto e acessar ele primeiro funciona, e inclusive os criados dinamicamente passam a funcionar.

https://plnkr.co/edit/RbOFEJ9hCO3T47BUqFzc?p=preview

Será que há uma luz, rsss.
Abraço.